# How to send PendingIntent to my service inside Intent

Tags: android

I want to tell my service what to do when it finish to perform an action.
So I want to send the service a `PendingIntent`, so it can start it (by using `PendingIntent.send()`)

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Intent newInt;
newInt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
newInt.setData( Uri.parse( "sms:052373"));
newInt.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, newInt, 0);
```

Now the question how to start to attach the `pendingIntent` to the `pendingIntent`?

I tried this for example:

```
NewIntent.putExtra("pendingIntent",pendingIntent);
startService(NewIntent);
```

But it doesn't work.

And in the service:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = (PendingIntent) intent.getParcelableExtra("pendingIntent");
pendingIntent.send();
```

Comment: "But it is doesn't work" is a useless description of your symptoms.

Comment: Thank you, next time I will be more specific

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I success!

see this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Intent ownIntent;

ownIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
ownIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:0523737233"));
ownIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");
Log.e("abc", "7");
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, ownIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Log.e("abc", "9");

ownIntent.putExtra("pendingIntent", pendingIntent);
ownIntent.putExtra("uriIntent", ownIntent.toUri(0));
startService(ownIntent);
```

and in the service:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = (PendingIntent) intent.getParcelableExtra("pendingIntent");
pendingIntent.send();
```