# Showing alert dialog on notification click when sent from Firebase Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using firebase push notification in my project.But whenever I click notification the **else** part is displayed always.I want to display notification text in that dialog when the notification is clicked.

Here is my code in `NotifService.class`:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_main)
                .setContentTitle("Update from Refer Ncert")
                .setContentText(""+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setLights(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS,1000,20000)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000})
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("notifmsg",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Here is the code in MainActivity's `onCreate()` to display the notification:

```
String notifmsg=getIntent().getStringExtra("notifmsg");

    if(notifmsg != null){
        new SweetAlertDialog(this)
                .setTitleText("Hello Readers!")
                .setContentText(notifmsg)
                .show();
    }
    else{
        new SweetAlertDialog(this)
                .setTitleText("Welcome Back")
                .setContentText("Continue reading your previous book by clicking on RECENT BOOK button below.")
                .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you define the intent, but you dont "send" it.

Add this to code your code after defining the pendingIntent and it should work:

```
pi.send();
```

Comment: did you start the service? have a look at that link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025797/how-to-send-pendingintent-to-my-service-inside-intent

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: No we cant popup alert dialog from out side the activity but  you can use broadcastreceiver it will triger alert dialog. once you got the notification, send the broadcast to mainactivity then broadcast will receive the message. By using this message you can pop up the alert dialog